# Name that entity (4)

Tags: riddle, word

Created or evolved whatever you please
walk in my shoes, which I can't seize

A computer originated world, I won't fathom
my death by some considered gruesome

I know how to live do not give me tips
but don't mourn me now, for I am in bits

suffocate me quick don't tarnish my produce
remember our sacrifice, our past abuse.

hints to make it easier:

> My name is changed once deceased
>  yet it holds the same meaning
>  well done! I am rare once the fires have ceased
>  I humble your buds once you begin feeding

Comment: "Created *OR* evolved"?

Comment: Ahh yeah its or my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be:

> Cow

Created or evolved whatever you please

> It is a creature of some sort. Definitely a physical thing. Refers to the religious arguments about "physical" existence.

walk in my shoes, which I can't seize

> Cow have no say about where they go.

A computer originated world,

> **C**omputer  **O**riginated  **W**orld (dear God.)

I won't fathom
my death by some considered gruesome

> The death of a cow even in a humane abbatoir can be quite brutal.

I know how to live do not give me tips

> "Leave me alone, don't tip me over!" (a past-time of certain people includes pushing cows over).

but don't mourn me now, for I am in bits

> Cows are sold in small pieces.

suffocate me quick don't tarnish my produce

> You must kill the cow quickly or the adrenaline can affect the meat. May also be some kind of reference to meat.

remember our sacrifice, our past abuse.

> Cows have been sacrificed since time immemorial.

My name is changed once deceased

> Cow becomes beef once killed.

yet it holds the same meaning

> It is the exact same thing.

well done! I am rare once the fires have ceased

> Beef can be "well done". But it "rare" if you take off the heat.

I humble your buds once you begin feeding

> Delicious

Comment: Brilliant another sandwich for you, the Computer Originated World is wikis disambiguation of COW and there not digitalised. Created or evolved due to fit religous beliefs. I also believe a past time for teenages is Cow tipping thus dont give them tips :D. Well done

Comment: @Oblongamous wow, that was tricky! nice one

Comment: thank you, although it appears avigrail is dominating the riddle scene, mine are childs play in comparison.

Answer (score 2):

> "A computer originated world"
>
> Are you a process running on a computer?
>
> "Walk in my shoes, which I can't seize"
>
> A computer process has a memory footprint (how much RAM is used), so you have figurative feet.  Not real shoes so they can't be seized.
>
> "my death by some considered gruesome"
>
> If you kill a process on Linux using "kill -9", the OS kills it immediately without giving the process a chance to clean up gracefully.  That could be considered gruesome.
>
> "I know how to live do not give me tips"
>
> A process's life is a pre-defined series of computer instructions that cannot be changed.
>
> "but don't mourn me now, for I am in bits"
>
> The memory that the process used is free again, representing bits that can be used for another process.

Comment: Nice answer unique but not what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

My guess:

> Dinosaurs

Created or evolved whatever you please
walk in my shoes, which I can't seize

> T-rex?

A computer originated world, I won't fathom
my death by some considered gruesome

> Dinosaur, again. Killed off in mass extinction.

I know how to live do not give me tips
but don't mourn me now, for I am in bits

> Mass extinction, again.

Suffocate me quick don't tarnish my produce
remember our sacrifice, our past abuse.

> The carbon remains, over time, could be anything from natural gas to diamonds